# $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(n)\to\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial

Tags: proof-verification, modules

> Show, that every $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(n)\to\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial (hence identical 0)

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}/(n)\to\mathbb{Z}$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism.
I have to show, that $f([m])=0$ for every $[m]\in\mathbb{Z}/(n)$

Can I do it like this:

If n=0 there is nothing to show. So $\mathbb{Z}\ni n\neq 0$.
Now, using that $f$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism we get:

$1.~~~f([m]+n[m])=f((n+1)[m])=(n+1)f([m])$ and also:

$2.~~~f([m]+n[m])=f([m]+[nm])=f([m]+[0])=f([m])$

Hence: $f([m])=(n+1)f([m])=nf([m])+f([m])\Leftrightarrow nf([m])=0$

Since $n\neq 0$ it has to be $f([m])=0$ for every $[m]\in\mathbb{Z}/(n)$

Is this proof done correct, or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do this exercise if you replace "$\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism" with "group homomorphism" - which are here equivalent?

Comment: Well, it should be kinda the same: $0=f([0])=f([nm])=f([n][m])=nf([m])$, so $f([m])=0$, since $n\neq 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is incorrect, since if $n=0$, $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and then we have more than one homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself, the identity and the zero homomorphism are examples. I suppose we should assume $n \neq 0$. The rest of the proof is correct, but I would prove it like this. The idea is that in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ every element $x$ satisfies the relation 
$$n\cdot x=0,$$
and since homomorphisms preserve all relations we have $n \cdot f(x)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, which implies $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you. So we need $n\neq 0$ as an assumption, since the question is not true else?

Comment: @Cornman Yes that's what I mean.